# Get the className of the tag within a Range object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have two custom context menu (one was written by my, the other one was already there). Mine show up only when a word is underlined because he is poorly written and the other one show up on table so the user can choose to add another line or to delete a line from this table.

The trouble I got is that the one working on table is blocking mine to execute if there is an error in the table and you want to correct it.

For this contextMenu, they write it so they got a range object from the place where the right click is done.

```
document.oncontextmenu = elementSelect;
function elementSelect(){
    Rng = document.selection.createRange();
}
```

I've tried to get the className of the tag inside the range object so if it match the class from my error tag (a span with class="error"), I do a simple return in the contextMenu for the table so it does not trigger.

```
var rngClassName = Rng(0).getAttribute("class").value;
alert("class =>" + rngClassName);
if(rngClassName == "error")
{
    return;
}
```

The Rng(0) is used after several time to retrieve somme attribute and work fine for them. But It seems that it does not work to get the class value, no value is return, the script stop execution at line `var rngClassName = Rng(0).getAttribute("class").value;` and no error is returned from the debugging (F12 in IE).

It is my first time working with Range object so I think I am missing something but don't know what.

Spec : IE5, Vanilla Javascript.

Comment: If you're using IE5, consider to update

Comment: @Pimskie I'm here since september and telling them that since september, sadly i'm just an outside ressource and just got the right to work and have no opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using element.classList .

with following methods : classList.add() , classList.remove() , classList.contains()

Comment: IN the contextMenu from the function elementSelect() I do not get the element selected. Only a range object is generated after the function start working

Answer (score 0):

**edit**: i see your comment now, and below won't work in IE5...

But if I understand your question correctly, you want to check the class of an element whitin the selection? I don't have IE5 so I checked it in 11 and Chrome. You could try something like this:

```
var selection = document.getSelection();
var selRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
var parentNode = selRange.startContainer.parentNode;
var hasError = parentNode.classList.contains('error');
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/spdwn7bo/1/ (select a text within 2 seconds :))